# Error with DateFormat in dart: "Trying to read -YYYY from 17-04-2020 at position 10"

Tags: flutter, dart

How to convert a string like '17-04-2020' which is in dd-MM-yyyy format to DateTime object in dart/flutter?

```
formatter = new DateFormat('dd-MM-YYYY');
formatter.parse(strDate);
```

I tried the above code and getting an error:

```
Trying to read -YYYY from 17-04-2020 at position 10
```

Comment: Hi, Aman. Did you try with lower-case Y's, like: `dd-mm-yyyy`?

Comment: Thanks, man! With the small case, it works :)

Comment: You're welcome :) I"ll just post an answer, if you can mark that as correct that would be great!

Comment: Oh, you may also try using just a single lower-case Y, it might work as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need lower-case Y's on your date pattern, use this:

```
"dd-MM-yyyy"
```

You can check the [docs here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/intl/DateFormat-class.html) for available date patterns.

In case you only need two digits of the year, you can also use `dd-MM-yy`.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
var myDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-y').parse('17-04-2020');
```

[intl package](https://pub.dev/packages/intl)